# Scala type polymorphism from parameter to return type, within type hierarchy

Tags: scala, types

I have some collection of type `Collection[SuperType]`. Stored in this collection are several values that are subtypes of `SuperType`, I would like the collection to only allow itself to contain one instance of each subtype (A bit like a set, but not).

I am trying to write a function that when given the companion object of one of the above mentioned subtypes, can return the first instance of the class the companion object belongs to.

Initially I tried with a Set as shown below, but T will suffer from type erasure, so the pattern matching will fail. I then also realised a Set wasn't suitable for this task, because I only want one occurrence of each subtype in the collection.

```
def get[T <: SuperType](target: T): Option[SuperType] =
  collection.collectFirst({
    case target: T => target
  })
```

My next, and current approach is using a map, where the key is a companion object and the value is an instance of the companion object's class. The type hierarchy is show below.

```
trait SuperType
trait SuperTypeValue

// Pretend this has some parameters
case class ExampleSubType extends SuperTypeValue

case object ExampleSubType extends SuperType {
  // value for use in later example
  val uniqueToObjectField: String = "hello"
}

val collection: Map[SuperType, SuperTypeValue] = // Some new map

def get(target: SuperType): Option[SuperTypeValue] =
  collection.get(target)
```

The above works well enough. However, I would like to preserve the type of the subtype that is used as the parameter, and use it as the return type. I believe the signature of the function would look something like this:

```
get[T <: SuperType](target: T): Option[T]

// So I could then do something like this
get(ExampleSubType) match {
  case Some(exampleSubType) => exampleSubType.uniqueToObjectField
  case _ => "nope"
}
```

Is this possible within scala? If so, how? If not, does this exist in other languages and what is it called?

Hopefully there are no glaring issues with this question, but it's 2am so I shall check things over again in the morning.

Comment: Could you not simply re-define the equals method to return true if both instances are the same, then directly use a Set ?

Comment: Good idea, that should work. Not sure how I feel about hijacking the equals method though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ClassTags`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.ClassTag) to get around the type erasure.  Instead of using the companion object, it might be easier to just provide the generic parameter explicitly:

```
import scala.reflect._

trait SuperType { val x: Int }

case class Foo(x: Int) extends SuperType
case class Bar(x: Int) extends SuperType

val collection = Set(Foo(1), Foo(2), Bar(3), Foo(4), Bar(5))
def get[T <: SuperType : ClassTag]: Option[T] = {
    collection.collectFirst {
        case target: T => target
    }
}
```

And then you can call:

```
get[Foo] //Foo(1)
get[Bar] //Bar(3)
```

Comment: Thanks, nice that I can just use a type parameter! I've changed `def get[T <: SuperType : ClassTag]: Option[SuperType]` to `def get[T <: SuperType : ClassTag]: Option[T]` so I can access members that might not be defined by `SuperType` and be unique to the subtype.

Comment: Oh of course that's much better!  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a hammer when you need a saw. You should just make a new class for this with a field for each type.

```
class SomeClass{
 a:TypeA
 b:TypeB
 c:TypeC

// if c extends b extends a maybe you want
// to prevent a TypeC being assigned to A I have no idea
// you can change these implementations to get the behavior you want
 addA(a:TypeA){ this.a = a}
 addB(b:TypeB){ this.b = b}
 addC(c:TypeC){ this.c = c}

}
```

Often novices try use collections for crazy purposes. Just because a collection holds data, doesn't mean any time you want to hold data you need one. You need to think about what your requirements are first before you decide what you are going to use, not the other way around, you will be on SO for the rest of your programming life if you take that approach.

Comment: I should have made this clear in my question, but I can't explicity know all the sub types. What if some user of a library wants to extend the super type for there own custom subtype? So I thought about using your saw, but a hammer is better for my use case.